# Drupal 7: Is it possible to print a cck field in the html.tpl file?

Tags: drupal, templates, drupal-7, cck

I am looking to use a cck field as the page title.
The $pagetitle variable is found in the html.tpl.php file. But it does not look as if I can access any nodes.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a module to do this, check out the [Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title) module.

> This module gives you granular control over the page title. You can specify patterns for how the title should be structured and, on content creation pages, specify the page title separately to the content's title.

I think there may be a bug with getting the CCK fields as available tokens but I believe there's a patch available for it.

Comment: I installed it yesterday but still ran into the problem of not being able to access field tokens. I will take a look at the patch though.

Comment: I found a patch for the tokens module that gives you the necessary field tokens that were previously unavailable. So I was able to use the Automatic NodeTitle module like you would in Drupal 6. http://drupal.org/node/691078#comment-4499612

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the relevant cck field and print its value instead of the default page title.  Try:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($node, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

... in your content type template file.  This will output all the contents of $node.  Beware, it will be messy, and it may take you a while to find what you're looking for!

Out of curiosity, why are doing this?

Comment: I needed to hide the default content title and replace it with a cck field named "Article Title" that could accept minor styling (bold, italics, ect. ) I accomplished this using the Automatic Nodetitle module. But I was unable to to use the "Article Title" field as a pattern because Drupal 7 shipped without the ability to use field tokens. So I could not put the "Article Title" in the path and also could not figure out how to print the field in the html.tpl.php file. But I found a patch to the token module that gave me the field tokens I needed, so all is well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using hook_preprocess_page() function and change the page title.
See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7#comment-24423